# NoSQL - wrapping my head around the duplication

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I come from a strong RDBMS background and I'm trying to wrap my head around how I'd structure a NoSQL project. From what I can see, normalisation is disregarded in favour of speed.

Say for example I have a blog and categories. In MySQL, I would have a `blog` table and a `categories` table joined by a `blog_categories` table to maintain the many-to-many relationship. I would simply use JOINs to display the data on the website accordingly.

Easy enough.

But with NoSQL:

1. Would I store the blog category along with the blog article in the same document? So if categories "general", "news" and "articles" were assigned to an article, I would save this data along with the article for each article applicable?
2. Does this then mean that if I wanted to rename "news" to "latest news", I would need to cycle through all blog articles and their categories and manually update each instance of the "news" category?

Answer (score 0):

You can store blog categories with the blog but it depends on how your blog will work. It will be faster but you can not:

1) Easily get a list of all tags
2) Change the name of a tag

How i tend to do it is have a table of tags and use a technique called manual referencing to populate data on screen.

In short it means having a collection of tags like :

```
{
    _id : tag1,
    tagName : "news"
}
```

Then in your blog:

```
{ 
    _id : blog1,
    blogTitle : "Title",
    blogBody : "..."
    tags : [
         tag1,
         .... 
    ]
}
```

That way you get the functionality you desire. for more information on manual referencing see mongodb documentation:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/#manual-references